# Running script before suspending while using dbus

Tags: suspend, d-bus, pm-utils

I have a file: `/etc/pm/sleep.d/85rmNvidiaModule`. In it I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in
    suspend)
        echo "Oh, this time we are doing a suspend to RAM. Cool!"
        sudo modprobe -r nvidia-uvm; optirun true
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Not doing anything useful"
    ;;
esac
```

This works well when I use `pm-suspend`, but does not work when I use the power button to suspend or when I do:

```
dbus-send --system --print-reply \ 
--dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 \
"org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Suspend" boolean:true
```

So the question is how do I run a script when I suspend using gnome-shell 3.14.1.

Also I am on Debian GNU/Linux jessie/sid, and most packages are pretty cleanly installed.